# How to analyze repeated cross-sectional survey

Tags: panel-data, multilevel-analysis, independence

I am relatively new to multilevel or mixed effects modeling, and I have been tasked by my employer to analyze survey data they collected from their organization. Their goal is to study the effect of different hybrid work arrangements (i.e., everyone works from home most of the time, some people come in to the office once or twice a week, etc.).

They have conducted two surveys collected two months apart. Questions repeat across surveys, and responses are on a Likert scale. Individuals are nested within branches, which are nested within departments. Individuals are assigned to different hybrid work conditions (our predictor or independent variable).

The problem is that individuals can complete the surveys at both timepoints, but the data is anonymized for privacy reasons, so I cannot simply do a repeated measures analysis. Normally, I might use ordinal logistic regression (e.g., CLMM), but I'm worried we may be violating the assumption of independent observations.

Is there any way to deal with this? Is it an option to analyze it at the branch or department level instead of the individual level? If so, what kind of model would you use and how would you define the model in terms of fixed or random effects?

Comment: Is assignment to work conditions at the individual level? Thus, within a given branch or department, some people will be assigned to work from home 95% and others will be assigned to come into the office 1-2 times per week?

Comment: Assignment is mostly at the branch level, and mandated by the department. There were a few individuals that self-selected into a work condition different from the rest of their branch, but we have that data so we can exclude them if necessary.

Comment: That's good to know and makes things a little easier. One more question about the eventual outcomes - will they be something like the mean of a set of items that form a scale? Or is it individual Likert items that you want to examine? The former would be much better than the latter, if at all possible.

Comment: Hi Erik (sorry for the late reply). Currently, the plan is to analyze individual Likert items, however some of them are related enough that my team has talked about putting them together to form a scale (however, it would not be a validated scale).